# How we do frequency shaping and amplitude shaping in hearing aid

Tags: frequency, amplitude

My project name is Digital Hearing Aid with frequency shaping and amplitude shaping using adaptive noise cancellation DSKC6713 DSP kit .
Almost I have done this noise cancellation using code studio ver 3.1( specifically used for this kit) 
Now I get stuck on frequency shaping and amplitude shaping ....after so many searches I still dont get any coding or algo ...can anyone help me..??

Comment: i'm wondering if the *"frequency shaping"* and *"amplitude shaping"* ain't the same thing.  something that an LTI filter does, or perhaps an adaptive time-varying linear filter.  or might "frequency shaping" mean mapping frequencies to other frequencies using something like a heterodyne oscillator or a pitch shifter?  i wonder if any of those are used in hearing aids.

Comment: By frequency shaping I mean that at some frequencies, gain ( amplitude ) is set to some level according to hearing aid....but how to do this in either matlab or code studio i cant get... Further more if any block in simulink is used for it then which block it will be???

Answer (score 1):

Merium:

To develop a better understanding of how frequency shaping is used in hearing aid processing, consider the following paper, "Physiological assessment of contrast-enhancing frequency shaping and multiband compression in hearing aids", Ian C. Bruce, Physiological Measurement, Volume 25, pages 945-956, 2004.  It is an older paper, but it provides a good overview of some ideas you may want to consider using in your project.  If you are a registered student at a college or university, you should have no trouble finding this article using the library's resources.

Due to the fact that common hearing impairment is associated with loss of high frequency sensitivity, I would suggest implementing a simple filter that provides gain for high frequencies and maintains the gain at lower frequencies.  You could do this using a multiband approach, which would give you more flexibility in setting the gain for each band, or a across single band that might be more readily realized in the DSKC6713 framework.  Have a look at this [article](https://www.hearinglink.org/your-hearing/hearing-tests-audiograms/what-do-different-audiograms-look-like/) to understand the different types of hearing loss.

As far as implementation goes, I would suggest using Matlab to develop and test your processing scheme prior to implementing it in the DSP C++ framework.

I hope this helps.

Michael.